# Liferay 6 :display a plain jsp page

Tags: liferay-6

Need your help guys. Any hint how can i dispaly a plain jsp in liferay context but without any liferay goodies, like theme, dockbar etc. Just a simple jsp page with some text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that a while ago and what I did was to create a servlet in a portlet listening to some kind of URL. Example :

```
http://your-server:8080/my-portlet/my-servlet
```

Inside this Servlet you can then do a forward to the JSP in your portlet.
Any user accessing this URL will then be forwarded to a full JSP without any liferay stuff.